# Migrating bulk mailing from Publicaster to O365?

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365

I'm looking at migrating some email related services off Publicaster. 
Looking at the [MS Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323(v=exchg.150).aspx#option1) that describes using 365 as an authenticated relay has a limit of 10K daily, and 30 messages per second.

If we opt to go this way, how exactly would this impact day to day operations? 
Would we need to have our developers batch out the processing of messages? 
Would these bulk messages be in the same queue as our users, and therefore slow down their reception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you link spells out that you should not use Office 365 for bulk message delivery.  It could affect delivery of messages from your tenant.

Another, arguably more helpful, article is here: [Exchange Online Service Limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx#Anchor_5).  As you have found, you are restricted to 30 messages per minute via SMTP.  Along with this, 10,000 recipients per day (per user).

I seriously doubt you could choke off your tenant by sending too many application emails, as you would get throttled well before causing a performance hit.  I'm assuming you're in the Office 365 Shared tenancy.  Dedicated might have different limits.

You would definitely risk having your tenant identified as spammy and having all of your emails go through "high-risk" pools for delivery.  This is not something you would want.

I echo Microsoft's recommendations.  You should use a different service for delivery of application-based emails, especially if you're doing bulk send.